# Run time error 5: Invalid procedure call in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy the selected combobox values into the adjacent cell, when I code for the same I am getting

> Run time error 5.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim projworkbook As Workbook
    Dim page1 As Worksheet
    Dim lColumn As Long
    Dim CopiedColName  as String

    Set projworkbook = ActiveWorkbook
    Set page1 = projworkbook.Worksheets("Project_Creation")

    lColumn = page1.Cells(13, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'Getting the last used column number

    If lColumn > 26 Then
        CopiedColName = Chr(Int((lColumn - 1) / 26) + 64) & Chr(Int((lColumn - 1) Mod 26) + 65) 'Converting the col number to col name
    Else
        CopiedColName = Chr(lColumn + 64)
    End If

    Me.Cells("CopiedColName" & 4).Text = Me.ComboBox1.Text '-> I am getting run time error at this line

End Sub
```

Comment: maybe change `"lColName"` to `CopiedColName `?

Comment: You can directly reference a cell with its row&column coordinates, in this case `Cells(4, lColumn).Text = ...`.

Comment: @AcsErno i tried your solution, i got run time error 1004: Unable to set the text property of the range class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
Me.Range(CopiedColName & 4).Value = Me.ComboBox1.Text '-> I am getting run time error at this line
```

Comment: Just to complete @DisplayName answer: `Text` is a [read-only property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/range-text-property-excel) of Range